# How to install OCX files to Wine

Tags: macos, wine, winetricks

I am using macOS 10.14.5,
and I am trying to run a Windows `exe` file. 
So I did `brew install wine`. 
Then, using `wine` to run the program yields the following error:

```
0009:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
```

My `wine` can run some other `exe` programs. Because of this, I thought I needed to install `mscomctl.ocx` and `comctl32.ocx` into `wine`. I copied the files from my Windows 7 computer to `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/` and added the corresponding overrides to the "Libraries" tab in `winecfg`. But I still got the same error.

I tried another way of installing the two files. 
I did `brew install winetricks zenity`,
and ran `sh winetricks dlls`. 
The GUI appeared, but it did nothing no matter what I clicked. 
Also, whenever I clicked anything on the GUI,
it outputs to the shell the same message

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Could not load a pixbuf from /org/gtk/libgtk/theme/Adwaita/assets/bullet-symbolic.svg.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
```

So how should I install [OCX](https://fileinfo.com/extension/ocx) files to `wine`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by removing non-ASCII characters from the name of the `exe` file. It is probably a bug of `wine`.